# Hibernate joined-subclass update

Tags: hibernate

I have a base class, `A`, and two subclasses, `B` and `C`. I have an instance of `B` that I am trying to update and change the type to `C`. The instance of `C` containing the updated data is transient, since I can't imagine there is anyway to modify a persistent instance.

When the transient instance is passed from the front-end to the service layer, a session begins and some checks are done to make sure it is a valid operation. During this session, a persistent instance (`B`) is retrieved. Assuming everything checks out, the transient object is (supposed to be) persisted.

It would seem that `.merge()` is the correct method to call, but we get a NonUniqueObjectException, as if we had called `.update()` (which doesn't work either, and shouldn't since the persistent instance is currently in the session).

I don't know why `.merge()` is giving the NonUniqueObjectException, since my understanding is that `.merge()` is intended for this situation; trying to update a entity that exists in the session with a transient instance. **My guess** was that it was upset that the persistent instance was a different class than the transient instance; I tested, and when I  call `.merge()` on a transient instance of the same class everything works as expected.

Not sure what to do next, I tried doing `.evict()` of the persistent instance and then `.update()` on the transient one, but that gives me a StaleObjectException. At this point, I can't come up with a solution. Are we trying to do something stupid, or could there be some sort of configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in Java, nor in hibernate. It's only possible via direct SQL queries in the database (bypassing hibernate). What you need to do, in hibernate terms, is delete `B` and create a new `C`. You'll need to take care of all references and relations (that obviously existed on `A`) by hand. C`will also be assigned a new id (in case that`A` has an auto increment id or something).

Comment: So the problem is with changing the subclass then? I'm a little let down that it isn't supported.

Comment: Yes. How can you do that in Java anyway? You cannot.